# titanium studio no refactoring in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, titanium

I started to learn titanium and I cannot find any options for refactoring. I'm used to pydev in eclipse with pretty good refactoring and to be honest I'm  bit straggling without it. Is there some eclipse module that I could install to eclipse to get some refactoring? I'm not java programmer so I don't really know what is available for it but I assume there must be something, right? so far googling didn't give me any reasonable answers.
thank you.
Pawel

Comment: Java? Vanilla eclipse with the JDT tools supports Java refactoring. Titanium  Studio is built for JavaScript.

Comment: I'm inexperienced with java/java script and I wrongly assumed it was java... anyway is there a way to get some refactoring going for java script?

Comment: There aren't any I am aware of for eclipse and JavaScript, the closest I have found are for intellij and webstorm.

Comment: thanks Josiah. I'm surprised that such a popular language has no tools to make using it easier... I guess I'm spoiled by PyDev.

Comment: I believe since its so unstructured its very hard to refactor things like in java, and since its not quite as old as python, but since WebStorm *does* have refactoring abilities I'm sure Eclipse / Aptana will get this ability too.